# Is Data Stored on Ethereum encrypted or only RLP encoded?

Tags: quorum, encryption, encoding

Is Data Stored on Ethereum encrypted or only RLP encoded? If data is not encrypted, is there some way to secure and encrypt it using AES encryption algorithm in cipher block chaining (CBC) or XTS mode with a 128-bit or 256-bit key?

Answer (score 1):

RLP is a method for serializing and deserializing data objects in a deterministic manner. Data stored on disk is RLP encoded into a compact Merkle Trie using a modified version of LevelDB.

If you wish to have encrypted data, then the data being transacted must be encrypted beforehand and decrypted when reading.

Comment: thanks. can leveldb be encrypted then? leveraging on-disk encryption